# Converting a JSON file to an R dataframe

Tags: r, json, dataframe, type-conversion, jsonlite

I know this question about transforming JSON to data frame has been asked a few times here but none of the answers provided have worked for me. For instance, I tried:

```
as.data.frame(ss_dtd)
```

And also:

```
test <- lapply(ss_dtd, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})
test2 <-as.data.frame(do.call("cbind", test))
```

Neither of these worked. There is also not much explanation of *how* this conversion works and what a JSON file is, which I think would be a useful addition to Stack Overflow's questions related to this topic, especially for people used to working strictly with DFs. I apologize in advance that I don't really know now to share a reprex with a JSON file. But I will do my best. I imported my JSON with:

```
ss_dtd <- jsonlite::fromJSON("original_json.json")
```

It looks like this (the red are emails).
[image]

The structure of the JSON file is below (with many more entries not shown).

```
    > str(ss_dtd)
List of 8232
 $ billy@fakeemail.com                     :List of 2
  ..$ joins        :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ project: chr "Sunflower Project"
  .. ..$ when   : chr "2020-09-18T13:09:53.789030"
  ..$ participation: list()
 $ sara@fakeemail.com                :List of 2
  ..$ joins        :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ project: chr "Project with Cells"
  .. ..$ when   : chr "2020-05-12T15:15:40.557827"
  ..$ participation: list()
 $ jerry@fakeemail.com                           :List of 2
  ..$ joins        :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ project: chr [1:2] "Water Project" "Sunflower Project"
  .. ..$ when   : chr [1:2] "2022-01-12T15:37:45.467523" "2020-10-15T18:57:59.623376"
  ..$ participation:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ project    : chr "Sunflower Project"
  .. ..$ when       : chr "2020-10-15T20:16:12.689239"
  .. ..$ repetitions: int 1
 $ randy@fakeemail.com                          :List of 2
  ..$ joins        :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ project: chr "Cloud Project"
  .. ..$ when   : chr "2022-02-17T20:05:24.991847"
  ..$ participation: list()
```

My desired output is:

```
                email join_or_participate            project                       when repetitions
1 billy@fakeemail.com                join  Sunflower Project 2020-09-18T13:09:53.789030          NA
2  sara@fakeemail.com                join Project with Cells 2020-05-12T15:15:40.557827          NA
3 jerry@fakeemail.com                join      Water Project 2022-01-12T15:37:45.467523          NA
4 jerry@fakeemail.com                join  Sunflower Project 2020-10-15T18:57:59.623376          NA
5 jerry@fakeemail.com         participate  Sunflower Project 2020-10-15T20:16:12.689239           1
6 randy@fakeemail.com                join      Cloud Project 2022-02-17T20:05:24.991847          NA
```

For a bit of context: this is data about people's engagement in different project. People could "join" a project and/or "participate" in a project. We recorded the time at which the people did either of these things and it was recorded in a JSON. If you "participated" in a project, we also recorded the number of repetitions you had (how many times you participated).

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: From the looks of your output it looks the structure is a list of lists.   Try to flatten the data on import: `jsonlite::fromJSON("original_json.json",  flatten=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but the structure is the same unfortunately.

Comment: The other options is to bind the data frame in each list, but to explain that and demonstrate it would, I would need a sampling of the JSON file.